# How to use multiple method inside ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to use multiple method( this.test(), this.flag = true ) inside ternary operator if condition success. But not working. Getting error like:

> ':' expected.

```
  public core = [1];
  public mare = [2];
  public flag:boolean = false;
  public msg:string;

  ngOnInit() { 
     this.core.length == 1 && this.mare.length == 1 ? this.msg = 'Done', this.flag = true : '';
  }

  test() {
     console.log('Done');
     console.log()
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n7txpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can you set `this.flag` inside of `test`?

Comment: Why are you using the ternary conditional operator? You're not assigning anything. Just use an `if` statement/block. `if (this.core.length == 1 && this.mare.length == 1) { this.test(); this.flag = true; }`.

Comment: Don't. It just makes your code hard to read. The conditional operator should only be used to for `result = condition ? a : b` where `result` is something you actually use. Don't make it complex. Don't make it have side effects. For your use case, use `if`!

Comment: Just use an if statement. Make your code readable. That would fail code review in almost every job I have worked at.

Comment: Just use an `if`. [Don't be clever.](https://guifroes.com/clever-code-is-bad/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't abuse ternary operators - they are not a replacement for `if` statements. They should only be used in extremely simple situations. Using `if` statements makes your code cleaner and more maintainable.

```js
if(this.core.length == 1 && this.mare.length == 1){
  this.msg = 'Done';
  this.flag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `()`

```
this.core.length == 1 && this.mare.length == 1 ? (this.test(), this.flag = true) : '';
```

or move `this.flag=true` into `test`

Though as pointed out in comments don't

> Why are you using the ternary conditional operator? You're not assigning anything. Just use an if statement/block. if (this.core.length == 1 && this.mare.length == 1) { this.test(); this.flag = true; }

Comment: Please Check my code

Comment: @EMahanK ok... what about it?